# What is the log of the beta function, how can it be simplified?

Tags: integration, logarithms, beta-function

$$B(x,y) = \int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1} \, dt$$
is the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). What is the meaning and simplification of the log of the beta function:

$$\log\left(\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1} \, dt\right) = \, ?$$

Comment: That's the third question about the same, essentally, isn't it? The beta function is just a ratio of gamma functions, and the gamma function is the gamma function, it can't be "simplified". It can be expressed by factorials for integer or half integer arguments, but you don't tell us if that's the case. And it wouldn't be much of a simplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well:
$$B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$
so:
$$\ln(B(x,y))=\ln(\Gamma(x))+\ln(\Gamma(y))-\ln(\Gamma(x+y))$$
then you can just use this instead??

Also there are identities relating to approximating $\ln(\Gamma(x))$ or finding its fourier series

---

Also notice that:
$$\ln\left(\prod a_i\right)=\sum\ln(a_i)$$